# How to calculate this surface integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

$\Sigma$ is the upper side of the surface $x^{2}+y^{2}+4 z^{2}=4(z \geq 0)$, now we need to calculate the value of $\iint_{\Sigma} \sqrt{4-x^{2}-4 z^{2}} d x d y$ (second-kind surface integral).

When I use the following code to calculate directly, the result is incorrect :

```
reg = Region[
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2 == 4 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]]
Integrate[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - 4z^2], {x, y, z} ∈ reg]
```

When I refer to the code in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143908/42417) for calculation, I can't get the correct result(the answer should be $\frac{32} {3}$). In addition, **I want to know why this method can't get the right results**, and **what's wrong with my thinking**.

```
region = Region[
   ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2 == 4 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]];

Integrate[#, {x, y, z} ∈ region] & /@ ({0, 0, Sqrt[
    4 - x^2 - 4 z^2]}.Normalize[{x, y, 4 z}])
```

But when I use the code of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83797/42417), I can get the result of $\frac{32}{3}$.

```
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
  surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> 
       param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}), {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, v2_}}] :=
  Integrate[
  Dot[field /. Thread[changeOfVars], 
   Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, 
   v2}]; 
DoubleContourIntegral[{0, 0, 
  Sqrt[4 - x^2 - 
    4 z^2]}, {({x, y, z} -> {u, v, Sqrt[4 - u^2 - v^2]/2}), {u, -2, 
   2}, {v, -Sqrt[4 - u^2], Sqrt[4 - u^2]}}]
```

What should I do?

**Analysis process for reference:**

The projection area of surface $\Sigma$ on xOy plane is $D_{x y}=\left\{(x, y) \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4\right\}$.

$$
\iint_{\Sigma} \sqrt{4-x^{2}-4 z^{2}} \mathrm{d} \mathrm{x} \mathrm{dy}=\iint_{\Sigma}|y| \mathrm{d} \mathrm{x} \mathrm{dy}=\iint_{x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4}|y| \mathrm{d} \mathrm{x} \mathrm{dy}\\
= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi} d \theta \int_{0}^{2} r^{2} \sin \theta d r 
=\frac{32}{3}
$$

There are the following conversion formulas in the textbook:

$$\iint_{\Sigma} R(x, y, z) d x d y=\pm \iint_{D_{x y}} R[x, y, z(x, y)] d x d y$$

$$\iint_{\Sigma} P(x, y, z) d y d z=\pm \iint_{D_{y z}} P[x(y, z), y, z] d y d z$$

$$\iint_{\Sigma} Q(x, y, z) d x d z=\pm \iint_{D_{x z}} Q[x, y(x, z), z] d x d z$$

---

$$\begin{array}{l}
\iint_{x} P(x, y, z) \mathrm{d} y \mathrm{d} z+Q(x, y, z) \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} x+R(x, y, z) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y \\
=\iint[P(x, y, z) \cos \alpha+Q(x, y, z) \cos \beta+R(x, y, z) \cos \gamma] \mathrm{d} S \\
=\pm \iint_{D}\left[P(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v)) \frac{\partial(y, z)}{\partial(u, v)}+Q(x(u, v), y(u, v)\right. \\
\left.z(u, v)) \frac{\partial(z, x)}{\partial(u, v)}+R(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v)) \frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(u, v)}\right] \mathrm{d} u \mathrm{d} v\\
 \overset{In particular, when z=z(x,y)}{\Longrightarrow} \pm \iint_{D}\left [-P(x, y, z(x, y)) \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial(x)}-Q(x, y\right. \\
\left.z(x,y)) \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial y}+R(x, y, z(x,y)) \right] \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y
\end{array}$$

**In particular, when $z=z(x,y)$:**

```
DForm[f_] := 
  f /. {Derivative[inds__][g_][vars__] :> Which[Length[{vars}] >= 2,
       Apply[Defer[D[g[vars], ##]] &, 
        Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{v_, 1} :> {v}, {v_, 0} :> 
           Nothing}], Length[{vars}] == 1, 
       Apply[Defer[Dt[g[vars], #]] &, 
        Transpose[{{vars, inds}}] /. {{v_, 1} :> {v}}]]} // 
   TraditionalForm ;
jacobian[u_, v_, {x_, y_}] := Det[( {
     {D[u, x], D[u, y]},
     {D[v, x], D[v, y]}
    } )] // DForm
(*In particular,when z=z(x,y)*)
jacobian[y, z[x, y], {x, y}]
jacobian[z[x, y], x, {x, y}]
jacobian[x, y, {x, y}](*Inner side of surface ∑*)
-jacobian[x, y, {x, y}](*Outside of surface ∑*)
```

$$\begin{array}{c}
\vec{n}=(\cos \alpha, \cos \beta, \cos \gamma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}}\left(-z_{x},-z_{y}, 1\right) \\
\therefore \cos \gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}} \\
\frac{d x d y}{d s}=\cos \gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}} \\
\frac{d y d z}{d s}=\cos\alpha=-\frac{z_{x}}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}} \\
\frac{d z d x}{d s}=\cos \beta=-\frac{z_{y}}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}}\\
\therefore \iint_{\Sigma} R(x, y, z) d x d y=\iint_{\Sigma} R(x, y, z) \cos \gamma d S \\
=\iint_{\Sigma} R[x, y, z(x, y)] \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z y^{2}}} d S \\
=\iint_{D_{x y}} R[x, y, z(x, y)] \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}} \cdot \sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}} d x d y \\
=\iint_{D_{xy}} R[x, y, z(x, y)] d x d y
\end{array}$$

---

$$\begin{array}{c}
\iint_{\Sigma} Q(x, y, z) d y d z=\iint_{\Sigma} Q(x, y, z) \cos \beta d S \\
=\iint_{\Sigma} Q[x, y, z(x, y)] \cdot \frac{-z_{x}}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z y^{2}}} d S \\
=\iint_{D_{xy}} Q[x, y, z(x, y)] \cdot \frac{-z_{x}}{\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}} \cdot \sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}} d x d y \\
=\iint_{D_{xy}} -Q[x, y, z(x, y)]z_{x}  d x d y
\end{array}$$

---

Comment: okay I think my now deleted answer was talking about the surface area, but I forgot you were integrating Sqrt[4 - x^2 - 4z^2] over that surface. However, my point still stands - you need to integrate over the `Disk[{0,0},2]` and multiply by the area element - I will update my answer.

Comment: I think you should post the integral on Mathematics stack exchange, because I do not believe 32/3 is the correct answer - see my revised answer for why. I believe Mathematica gives the correct answer when it does `Integrate[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - 4z^2], {x, y, z} ∈ reg]`

Comment: I think the reason you get 32/3 with `DoubleContourIntegral` is because you're integrating a vector field that's pointing directly up: `DoubleContourIntegral[{0, 0, Sqrt[4 - x^2 - 4 z^2]},...` and you have a dot product with the normal that measures the flux of the field. So in that sense it's correct that it's 32/3, however, the other surface integral that you're having problems with is scalar - it accumulates a scalar field over infinitesimal surface patches, and the dot product doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: I can illustrate the above discrepancy very simply. Let's take the curved surface of a cylinder and the function z=1. There is obviously no flux over the boundary because the normals are all perpendicular. Using `DoubleContourIntegral[{0, 0, 
  1}, {({x, y, z} -> {Sqrt[1 - v^2], Sqrt[1 - u^2], z}), {u, -1, 
   1}, {v, -Sqrt[1 - u^2], Sqrt[1 - u^2]}}]` we get zero. However, a scalar surface integral of 1 would give the true surface area (z Pi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been back and forth trying to work out why Mathematica was getting the surface integral 'wrong'. But Mathematica **can** do surface integrals properly. See this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88210/72682). It turns out your original calculation with the region is correct after all:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2 == 4 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}];
Integrate[Sqrt[4 - x^2 - 4z^2], {x, y, z} ∈ reg]

(* result: 32/9 (2 EllipticE[3/4] + EllipticK[3/4]) *)

N[%]

(* 16.2796 *)
```

Note: My answer before of 32/3 was wrong because an incorrect usage of nested `With` and the derivative was giving the wrong surface element of 1.

All that remains is to show that your integrals are incorrect and that the surface integrals are a lot more complicated:

$$
\iint_{\Sigma} \sqrt{4-x^{2}-4 z^{2}} \mathrm{d}\Sigma=\iint_{\Sigma}|y| \mathrm{d} \Sigma
$$

We substitute $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and $z=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4-r^2}$.
The element of area for cylindrical coordinates is $r\ \mathrm{d}r\ \mathrm{d}\theta$ [(see $S_z$ here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Line_and_volume_elements). This means that:

$$
\mathrm{d}\Sigma=\left\|\frac{\partial{\Sigma}}{\partial{r}}\times\frac{\partial{\Sigma}}{\partial{\theta}}\right\|\cdot r\ \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta=r \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \left| \frac{r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\right| ^2+1}
$$

$$
\iint_{\Sigma} \sqrt{4-x^{2}-4 z^{2}} \mathrm{d}\Sigma=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|r\sin(\theta)|\cdot r \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \left| \frac{r}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\right| ^2+1}\ \mathrm{d}\theta\ \mathrm{d}r
$$

The result of this integral is quite messy, involving elliptical functions.

I will show how to calculate it in both cartesian and cylindrical:

**Cartesian**:

```
With[{z2 = (4 - x^2 - y^2)/4},
  With[{z = Sqrt[z2]},
   Integrate[
    Sqrt[4 - x^2 - 4 z2] Sqrt[1 + D[z, x]^2 + D[z, y]^2], {x, 
      y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2]]
   ]
  ] // FullSimplify

(* 8/27 (-24 - 24 I Sqrt[2] 3^(1/4) EllipticE[1/2 - 7/(8 Sqrt[3])] - 
   12 (-2 + Sqrt[3]) EllipticE[-8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] + 
   12 (-2 + Sqrt[3]) EllipticE[
     I ArcCsch[3^(1/4) + 3^(3/4)], -8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] - 
   60 (2 + Sqrt[3]) EllipticF[
     I ArcCsch[3^(1/4) + 3^(3/4)], -8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] + 
   I Sqrt[6 (168 + 97 Sqrt[3])] EllipticK[1/2 - 7/(8 Sqrt[3])] + 
   60 I (2 + Sqrt[3]) EllipticK[97 + 56 Sqrt[3]]) *)

N[%]

(* 16.2796 *)
```

**Cylindrical**:

```
z = Sqrt[4 - r^2]/2;
sz[r_, \[Theta]_] := {r, \[Theta], z}
el = Norm[Cross[D[sz[r, \[Theta]], r], D[sz[r, \[Theta]], \[Theta]]]];
Integrate[Abs[r Sin[\[Theta]]]*el*r, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 2}]

(* 8/27 (-24 - 24 I Sqrt[2] 3^(1/4) EllipticE[1/2 - 7/(8 Sqrt[3])] + 
   24 EllipticE[-8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] - 
   12 Sqrt[3] EllipticE[-8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] - 
   24 EllipticE[I ArcCsch[3^(1/4) + 3^(3/4)], -8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] + 
   12 Sqrt[3]
     EllipticE[I ArcCsch[3^(1/4) + 3^(3/4)], -8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] - 
   120 EllipticF[I ArcCsch[3^(1/4) + 3^(3/4)], -8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] - 
   60 Sqrt[3]
     EllipticF[I ArcCsch[3^(1/4) + 3^(3/4)], -8 (12 + 7 Sqrt[3])] + 
   I Sqrt[6 (168 + 97 Sqrt[3])] EllipticK[1/2 - 7/(8 Sqrt[3])] + 
   120 I EllipticK[97 + 56 Sqrt[3]] + 
   60 I Sqrt[3] EllipticK[97 + 56 Sqrt[3]]) *)

N[%]//Chop

(* 16.2796 *)
```

Both of these numerical results agree with the result from integrating over the `ImplicitRegion` except the expressions weren't as simple. Presumably there are some different coordinate transformations going on internally which leads to the nicer expression `32/9 (2 EllipticE[3/4] + EllipticK[3/4])`.

Comment: I refer to the code of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83797/42417). The result of this code is $\frac{32}{3}$: `DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
   surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> 
        param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}), {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, 
      v2_}}] := 
  Integrate[
   Dot[field /. Thread[changeOfVars], 
    Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];

DoubleContourIntegral[{0, 0, Sqrt[
  4 - x^2 - 
   4 z^2]}, {({x, y, z} -> {u, v, Sqrt[4 - u^2 - v^2]/2}), {u, -2, 
   2}, {v, -Sqrt[4 - u^2], Sqrt[4 - u^2]}}]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have added some knowledge points to the post.